# Some Symbols to Ask Questions

Tags: discussion

How can i make a sum symbol to ask a math related physics question?

I mean Riemann Sum.

What is the short cut of Riemann sum or how can i ask a question that has mat symbols, formulas?

Comment: I always open my WinEdt to find out how the symbols I use not often enough are LaTex ed.

Comment: $\sum$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula may be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with [the section in the FAQ on symbols and notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#notation), and then search the web for [help with LaTeX's mathmode symbols](https://www.google.com/search?q=LaTeX%20math%20symbols).

Or you can find a post that *has* the symbol you're looking for and use the "edit"
button to get a look at the source ans see what they used.

Comment: Or just right click the symbol and select "Show Math as" then "TeX commands".

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can try [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). Just draw the symbol you are looking for, and this website will look it up in the database.